# JavaScript/CSS - buttons overlaying video

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I created a simple html/javascript/css to learn about it. It is a video with buttons inside. I want the buttons to be invisible until the video plays for 5 seconds where the video will then pause and the buttons will appear. I was able to get this to work with 1 button but now I want to expand it to 3 buttons. For some reason when I run it, when the video hits 5 seconds, button 2 and 3 jumps down to the next line. I don't understand why it is doing that. Also, how do I make all the buttons invisible until the video pauses at 5 seconds? I'd like for it to show then, and then after I select a button, have the buttons disappear again.

Here is my html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <video id="myvid" width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <div id="group1">
        <button onclick="one()">one</button>
        <button onclick="two()">two</button>
        <button onclick="three()">three</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
var video = document.getElementById("myvid");
var button = document.querySelector("button"); //tried changing to #group1 but it still does the exact same as "button"

video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
    if(this.currentTime >= 5 && this.currentTime <= 6) { 
    this.pause();
    button.style = "display: block";
    }
});
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#group1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
}
```

I had "display: none;" inside #group1 and that doesn't allow the buttons to be displayed but then I can't figure out in my javascript how to display it when the video pauses.

Comment: so basically you are only grabbing the first button, what happens if you change "button" to `#group1`?? what you will want to do is change button to #group1 and then in your #group1 styles set the display to none

Comment: @JuvenileSnow I've tried changing "button" to "group1" and setting my display:none but nothing changes :(

Comment: you are also using style wrong try this button.style.display = 'block';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I make all the buttons invisible until the video pauses at 5 seconds?

Add a default style with `visibility: hidden` to your button group.

```
#group1 {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

> For some reason when I run it, when the video hits 5 seconds, button 2 and 3 jumps down to the next line. I don't understand why it is doing that.

Its mostly because, you haven't applied any CSS to your buttons or your first button has a style of `display:block`. So give style `display: inline-block` to all your buttons.

```
#group1 button {
  display: inine-block;
}
```

And on click of your button, again apply style `visibility: hidden` to your div. So it would make it go.

check my example

```js
var video = document.getElementById("myvid");
var btnGroup = document.querySelector("#btn-group");

video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
    if(this.currentTime >= 5 && this.currentTime <= 6) { 
     this.pause();
     btnGroup.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
});

function one() {
 btnGroup.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```css
#btn-group {
  visibility : hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <video id="myvid" width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <div id="btn-group">
        <button onclick="one()">one</button>
        <button onclick="two()">two</button>
        <button onclick="three()">three</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

You can also use `display: block` and `display: none`. If you use display, the element wont take occupy any space. If you use `visibility: hidden` it will continue to occupy the space in the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'document.querySelectorAll("button")' but not 'document.querySelector("button")'.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector` will select only first item. You can use `document.getElementsByClassName`.

Add class to each button

```
    <button class="myclass" onclick="one()">one</button>
    <button class="myclass" onclick="two()">two</button>
    <button class="myclass" onclick="three()">three</button>
```

Use class selector.

`var button = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");`

Change style to all buttons with loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    button[i].style = "display: block";
}
```